# Does neural network in brain form cycles?

Tags: neuroscience

In other words is it possible for dendrite of neuron A to be connected with axon of neuron B and at the same time dendrite of neuron B to be connections with axon of neuron A (or similarly for any larger number of neurons)?

If so, are there any statistical data on number of such cycles in average human brain?

Comment: I don't think such direct loops exist. I haven't even heard much about small indirect feedback loops in neurons though feedforward are well known.

Comment: I wouldn't call them "cycles". "Both inhibitory and excitatory coupling were observed between pairs of mitral cells." from [Reciprocal intraglomerular excitation and intra- and interglomerular lateral inhibition between mouse olfactory bulb mitral cells](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2290433/). It's dense reading but I think it's giving an example of your A and B.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In general neural networks are a lot less simple and directed than ANNs or artificial circuitry - connections can be inhibitory or excitatory, vary widely in strength etc etc. So unsurprisingly yes, recurrence [is observed](https://www.bcf.uni-freiburg.de/people/papers-kumar/kumr13-1.pdf) in actual neural networks. I don't know of any statistics on the frequency of such network structures, or even if such exists. Our knowledge of the brain at this fine level is still limited I think, the more global attempt to map 'the connectome' generally consider things at a higher resolution.

Comment: "...inhibitory or activating." I believe the official term is excitatory, not activating.

Comment: @CDB - true, fixed